# Angularjs Directives Performance - Pass an Array vs Passing Single Objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Performance wise, is it better to pass individual objects to a directive like so

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users">
  <user-info user="user"></user-info>
</div>

// user-info directive
<div>
  <span>{{ user.username }}</span><br>
  <span>{{ user.email }}</span>
</div>
```

Or pass the entire array to a single directive:

```
<user-list users="users"></user-list>

// user-list directive

<div ng-repeat="user in users">
  <span>{{ user.username }}</span><br>
  <span>{{ user.email }}</span>
</div>
```

I imagine the second option would be a better idea since  the directive's methods wouldn't get called for every item in the array

Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 2):

**`Definitely`** its the later way, because it does not have to **`render`** the element each time you iterate over users.

Angularjs starts to have performance issues when you have more watchers (which are responsible for handling your data-binding).  Reducing the number of data bindings will definitely help.

Comment: Can you explain which element you mean. There is extra element in 1st approach, but if I remove <div> from user-info template -- elements count is same.